# Random PC restart

Tags: windows-7

I was watching a youtube video and all of a sudden windows firewall appeared and said something about a weird file. I closed the window and continued with what I was doing, not knowing what the thing was about. Not 15 seconds later another window popped up and said something about a virtually signed driver and my pc restarted. I couldn't read all the text because it just closed itself after 2 seconds. My pc just turned on and I need to know what this is. After researching a bit I found a few errors in the Even Viewer that appeared at the time when my pc restarted. Here's what the first one says. "Event filter with query "SELECT * FROM __InstanceModificationEvent WITHIN 60 WHERE TargetInstance ISA "Win32_Processor" AND TargetInstance.LoadPercentage > 99" could not be reactivated in namespace "//./root/CIMV2" because of error 0x80041003. Events cannot be delivered through this filter until the problem is corrected."
The second one is a warning and it says: A timeout was reached (30000 milliseconds) while waiting for the syshost32 service to connect. The third one is a warning again: Name resolution for the name miodzaki.bit timed out after none of the configured DNS servers responded. The fourth one is an error: A timeout was reached (30000 milliseconds) while waiting for the syshost32 service to connect.
After researching some more stuff I found out that a file named syshost.exe is connected to many errors on my pc, including the one that happened before my pc restarted. It's located in C:\Windows\Installer{F5A90208-4BD4-0D6D-2192 and it has almost no info on who made it and things like that. What do you recommend that I do? Should I try to remove this or wait one or two days until I completely reset my system?

Comment: We the actual text of either of the warnings if you want help.

Comment: I really couldn't read the message, all I could read is that it was about some driver and the first message that popped up was about a file like this "fgfd434f_4344f43_325454ff" and it said something about an update.

Comment: Start by checking your Event Logs... As-is there's not nearly enough info here for anyone to help.

Comment: @user546943 - We cannot help without at least one of the warnings or the driver name.

Comment: There are a few errors in the Even Viewer that appeared at the time when my pc restarted. Here's what the first one says.
Event filter with query "SELECT * FROM __InstanceModificationEvent WITHIN 60 WHERE TargetInstance ISA "Win32_Processor" AND TargetInstance.LoadPercentage > 99" could not be reactivated in namespace "//./root/CIMV2" because of error 0x80041003. Events cannot be delivered through this filter until the problem is corrected.

Comment: The second one is a warning and it says: A timeout was reached (30000 milliseconds) while waiting for the syshost32 service to connect.
The third one is a warning again: Name resolution for the name miodzaki.bit timed out after none of the configured DNS servers responded.
The fourth one is an error: A timeout was reached (30000 milliseconds) while waiting for the syshost32 service to connect.

Comment: That's all that happened in those 5 minutes before my pc restarted, I hope that's enough info..

Comment: Update your question.

Comment: I edited the question and added more info, if that's what you were asking for.

Comment: @Ramhound All I need to know is am I safe for the next few days? Can anything bad happen to my pc until I restore it? I know you don't have much info but you seem to be a professional at this stuff, what do you think?

Comment: Take 3 minutes to format your question.

Comment: I was going to read your question, but I'm worried that I might need to breathe at some point.

Answer (score -2):

This looks like a virus via flash-player browser-plugin. Your PC might not be save anymore, and I´d strongly recommend to check for viruses (via boot-cd). Ideally you erase your drive and playback a backup. Hopefully you have not activated Java inside your browser. The site YouTube.Com should be save to use, but maybe you were surfing somewhere else too. Don´t ask why sandboxing is still not implemented or used correctly.

Comment: even if sandboxing was implemented, its entirely possible, to escape it.  It has been done before dozens of times, on ever single platform, where sandboxing is implemented to some degree.

Comment: I'm already preparing important files to burn on a cd because I'm restarting my entire system this week.. I do use Google Chrome and I think Google Chrome doesn't use Java, I hope I'll be ok these few days..

Comment: @Ramhound: If sandboxing would be implemented correctly, there won´t  be any possibility for any malware. Certainly incorrect sandboxing software, or incorrect virtualization hardware contains some risk for not so common, highly sophisticated malware. But it´s better to have some unreliable sandboxing/virtualization than to have absolutely no protection.

Comment: After researching some stuff I found out that a file named syshost.exe is connected to many errors on my pc, including the one that happened before my pc restarted. It's located in C:\Windows\Installer\{F5A90208-4BD4-0D6D-2192 and it has almost no info on who made it and things like that. What do you recommend that I do? Should I try to remove this or wait one or two days until I completely reset my system?